# Just installed Puppy Linux to hard drive (full install), but it doesn't boot

Tags: boot, boot-loader, puppy-linux

When I boot without the USB mounted I get this message even though the OS is installed in the hard drive:

```
wee 0>find --set -root /grldr
(0x80,0)
wee 0> /grldr
wee 13>
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my first answer.
People with Toshibas had an issue like this.

Keep in mind, on Puppy uses "Boot2Dos", so the Grub Menu you see isn't entirely grub.

I got mine working non-uefi boot in bios, creating a FAT32 500 MB partition, setting it to boot (the flag) using GPARTED in the live CD.

- sda: (hdd0)

  - sda1: (hd0,0) 500 MB – FAT32 – Install the Bootloader here.
  - sda2: (hd0,1)  20 GB – EXT4  – Install Puppy Here
  - sda3: (hd0,2)  20 GB – EXT4  – Primary

If you want more than that, you need to create logical partitions. This is how partitions were structed in the old days. And if you have a laptop with a HDD under 2 TB, it's dead easy to use this system for multi booting.

When you install puppy, at the end it provides you with a txt file,
you need to put that into the `Menu.lst` to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as the original poster.  I did a FULL install of Bionic Pup and i also was getting the "wee" message.

I figured it out...  After successfully installing Grub4dos, a text document opens with instructions that tell you to copy and paste a certain part into the menu.lst.

Once i did that and rebooted, my 2009 Acer Aspire One netbook finally booted to the menu where i could select and boot into Puppy Linux.